# Async fetch results not transferred to data function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the code below in the file `_slug.vue`

`{{ feed }}` always returns an empty array.
The `console.log(this.feed)` in the async fetch functions logs the correct data( an array of three objects) returned from the api call(a custom strapi controller). But again, feed is empty in the page itself.

`{{ category }}` is works as intended, both in the page and the console.log inside the async fetch function.

I have tried change the api call to one that does not require a param and that works in another page and I still get an empty array.

What am I missing?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Feed - {{ category }}</h1>
    <p>{{ feed }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      feed: [],
      category: this.$route.params.slug,
    }
  },
  async fetch({ params }) {
    const category = params.slug
    console.log('slug: ' + category)
    this.feed = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:1337/api/getCategory/${params.slug}`
    ).then((res) => res.json())
    console.log(this.feed)
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fetch()` without anything inside of `()` otherwise, you'll be using the old fetch as explained here: stackoverflow.com/a/68820416/8816585

Access the params through regular `this.$route.params.slug`.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Kissu resolved my issue, not passing { params } to fetch() and using this.$route.params.slug instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your category property works as expected because you're setting it directly in the data function. You're not actually setting the category in the fetch function. I think that your problem is with the fetch function not being placed in the "methods" property. Try refactoring the code as follows: (note the fetch function placed in the methods object)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Feed - {{ category }}</h1>
    <p>{{ feed }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async fetch({ params }) {
      const category = params.slug;
      console.log("slug: " + category);
      this.feed = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/getCategory/${params.slug}`).then((res) => res.json());
      console.log(this.feed);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      feed: [],
      category: this.$route.params.slug,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```